# Java: Printf(%.2f,arg) displays f$ff instead of f.ff. What might cause this?

Tags: java, formatting, printf

```
public class Ex51 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter as many integers as you wish. Enter 0 to stop." + "\nReturns "
                + "\nNumber of negative integers input. " + "\nNumber of positive integers input." + "\nTotal sum."
                + "\nMean.");

        int i = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        int minusCount = 0;
        int plusCount = 0;
        float mean = 0;
        boolean isZero = false;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            temp = input.nextInt();
            if (temp == 0 && i == 0) {
                isZero = true;
                break;
            } else if (temp < 0) {
                minusCount++;
            } else if (temp > 0)
                plusCount++;
            if (temp != 0) {
                i++;
                sum += temp;
                mean = (float) sum / (float) i;
            }
        } while (temp != 0);

        if (!isZero) {
            System.out.printf("\nThe number of positives is: %d" + "\nThe number of negatives is: %d"
                    + "\nThe total is: %d" + "\nThe average is: %.2f", plusCount, minusCount, sum, mean);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No numbers are entered except 0.");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a sample run:

> Enter as many integers as you wish. Enter 0 to stop.
>  Returns 
>   Number of negative integers input. 
>  Number of positive integers
>   input.
>  Total sum.
>  Mean.
>  
>  Enter an integer: 8
>  Enter
>   an integer: 6
>  Enter an integer: 20
>  Enter an integer: -2
>   Enter an integer: 0
>  
>  The number of positives is: 3
>  The
>   number of negatives is: 1
>  The total is: 32
>  The average is:
>   8$00

My problem is right at the bottom: 8$00
When I specify %.2f for the float with no special characters in between.
The desired output would be "8.00" for arg mean.
I posted all of the code because I think I would make obvious any beginner mistakes fairly obvious and if not is there any issues with my settings.
I'm running this on Eclipse with jre9.

Comment: If you `System.out.println(".,");`, what shows up?

Comment: Supposing that your Java installation is not downright broken, there are two main possibilities: (1) the default charset of your JVM is mismatched with the charset used by the terminal in which you are running your application, or (2) the default locale used by your program has `'$'` configured as its decimal separator symbol.  It definitely seems to be a local problem, for your code produces the output you expect [at ideone](https://ideone.com/F7EElg).

Comment: @Ryan When I System.out.println(".,") the output is ".,".

Comment: @John Bollinger JRE-9 and Eclipse Oxygen. Do you have any suggestions on how to reconfigure the charset?

Comment: @PauloMartins, The output of your `println()` test seems to indicate that it is not a charset problem.  That makes it very likely indeed that it is a problem with the decimal separator configured in the default Locale.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `System.out.println(((DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getInstance()).getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator());`?

Comment: It outputs that some characters cannot be compiled using Cp152, suggests me to change to UTF-8.

Comment: Problem solved:
Seems like there is a bug concerning java 9 with eclipse oxygen.

As soon as I uninstalled jdk 1.9 and reinstalled jdk 1.8 the output was displayed as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a number before '.' for example 2.2f.

For the rest of the code, for initializing you can do it all in one line. The last if statement is useless because you already verified in the first if it is 0, so you dont need a condition for this one. And you will not get there anyway because your while condition is that temp is not 0.
For the mean you can do:
mean = (float)(sum/i);
I think you are just complecating your life.
you could do this:

```
    int temp = 1;
    int positive = 0;
    int negative = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0; 
    while (temp != 0)
    {
       System.out.print("Please enter an integer:");
       temp = input.nextInt();
       if(temp == 0)
          //your print statement here
       else if(temp > 0)
         positive ++;
       else
         negative ++;
       sum += temp;
       i++;
    }
```

Comment: A number preceding the '.' in the field descriptor would represent a field width.  It is optional, whether a precision is specified or not, so omitting it is not a problem.  Overall, then, this does not answer the question.